# Combine existing figures into one pdf of figure PYTHON

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib

I can't find a solution that works for me.

I have a number of already existing figures i created earlier and want to combine them into one pdf landscape page. the graphic files are standard matplotlib savefig's as .png.

So how can I simply combine, say four, plots to save them as one pdf page with python? I would like to arrange them like this:

```
*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*
|                                                                                   |
|    *-------------------------------*         *-------------------------------*    |
|    |                               |         |                               |    |
|    |                               |         |                               |    |
|    |         fig 1                 |         |       fig 2                   |    |
|    |                               |         |                               |    |
|    |                               |         |                               |    |
|    *-------------------------------*         *-------------------------------*    |
|                                                                                   |
|                                                                                   |
|    *-------------------------------*         *-------------------------------*    |
|    |                               |         |                               |    |
|    |                               |         |                               |    |
|    |         fig 3                 |         |       fig 4                   |    |
|    |                               |         |                               |    |
|    |                               |         |                               |    |
|    *-------------------------------*         *-------------------------------*    |
|                                                                                   |
*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*
```

is there some very simple way to to this?

Thanks for the help,

Tobias

Comment: You can also use [reportlab](http://www.reportlab.com/opensource/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered making an html template that assembles the images in proper positions and then using a python pagkage (eg.: [pdfkit](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfkit)) to convert your html "page" to a pdf document?

Would it be a valid solution for you?

Hope it helps!

---- EDIT ----

I got a working example using my suggestion.
Assuming that you have already installed *pdfkit* and *wkhtmltopdf* as instructed in the link I sent previously, suppose you have the following files (I will show each file content ahead) in a directory called *results*:

- results

  - fig1.png
  - fig2.png
  - fig3.png
  - fig4.png
  - template.html
  - style.css
  - html2pdf.py

The png files are obviously your plots image files.

The **template.html** file contains the following code:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="ext_container">
            <div id="row1">
                <div id="fig1_container">
                    <img src="fig1.png"> </img>
                </div>
                <div id="fig2_container">
                    <img src="fig2.png"> </img>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="row2">
                <div id="fig3_container">
                    <img src="fig3.png"> </img>
                </div>
                <div id="fig4_container">
                    <img src="fig4.png"> </img>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The **style.css** contains the following code:

```
ext_container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
}

#fig1_container {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

#fig2_container {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: 100px;
}

#fig3_container {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

#fig4_container {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: 100px;
}

#row2 {
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
}

img {
    max-width: 300px;
    max-height: 300px;
}
```

And the **html2pdf.py** script contains the following lines (as documented in [pdfkit usage](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfkit)):

```
import pdfkit
pdfkit.from_file('template.html', 'output.pdf')
```

Then all you have to do is calling the **html2pdf.py** script from command line.

Hope you get this working!

Comment: unfortunately i'm not that good in html and i'm simply looking for a way to create a pdf and place some pictures in it... i thought there would have to be some kind of easy way for this...

Comment: I'm trying to make a working example using the solution I suggested. I'll post it here as soon as I get it to work.

Comment: That looks actually really great, thank you very much for that. just one question... i'm getting an error, that pdfkit seems not to bee installed and installing wkhtmltopdf from your link didnt cure that...

Comment: Okay, i did manage to get it to work and now i simply have to adjust to my favored settings. thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

How about using [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org)? You can simply import the pngs and save the result as pdf.

If you need to do this for many pngs, you could save to svg in tnkscape and use it as a template. With a simple python script you could replace the filenames of the png source in the svg and use inkscape again to create pdfs.